# A recursively enumerable language and a recursively enumerable set

Tags: terminology, computability

I am confused between these two terminologies: recursively enumerable language, recursively enumerable set.

Do they have the exactly same meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they do not have *exactly* the same meaning. A language is a set of strings, whereas a set can be virtually anything. Usually such a set is a set of (natural) numbers, but we also can consider sets of graphs.

However, when the sets are accepted or generated by Turing machines, then they have to be represented on a tape (for input or output). This means they have to be represented as strings anyhow. Hence for the Turing machine itself there is no difference. Only for the human beholder there is an interpretation of the string as number or graph.

Comment: I am sorry but this is just not correct at all.

Comment: Good example: sets of functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ are always undecidable -- a priori, we don't have a way to write a function to a TM tape. The *language* of some (or all) *encodings* of said functions, however, may well be decidable.

Comment: Sorry @Raphael, a good example of what? You mean of a set rather than a language?

Comment: An example where the distinction between set and (associated) string language matters.

Comment: Could you clarify why "sets of functions ℕ→ℕ are always undecidable"

Answer (score -1):

The language describes the set, it defines how to decide if a given element is part of the set or not.

The complexity in your given case for that decision is recursively enumberable.
You could create a Turing Machine to make this decision, or an computer program in any other prorgamming language like e.g. Java.

Example:
The Java compiler tells you if the given input is part of Java or not. 
Language: Java
Set: All possible programs accepted by the Java Compiler
Complexity: Time a Turing Machine will take to decide if input is part of the set defined by the language.

Personally I would say the terms can be regarded as the same thing at least in spoken language.

Comment: No. In computer science, a language is a set of strings, not a definition of how to decide something (an algorithm). So, yes, the set of Java programs forms a language but so does the set of strings with an even number of a's in them.

Comment: Yes! How to define that set of strings? In both examples, Java and even number of a's, there are unlimented members in the SET! How do you now if s string is part of the language? What makes one language more complex then another one (e.g. Nondeterministic contextfree languages)?

Comment: In addition: you are saying it be yourself: the set of strings form a language. This set may have infinit members. You need a way to decide if an element is element of the set. That is what complexity is about!

Comment: This question isn't about how you decide membership of languages or about complexity so a discussion of that isn't relevant. (And comments aren't the right place for discussions, anyway.)

Comment: The language defines which elements are part of the set which form the language (your own words). Your comment above is just not correct. The question is exactly about the two mentioned points.

Comment: No! A language **is** a set of strings. Period. You might interpret the set of strings as having some meaning (i.e., interpret it as defining something) but that is your interpretation. A language is a set of strings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16855/discussion-between-martin-meeser-and-david-richerby).

Comment: If a language is JUST a set of strings you would not be able to determine difference in complexity!

Comment: The language defines the set. Period. :-P

Comment: @DavidRicherby There are so called "undecidable" languages! How can a set of string be "undecidable"

Comment: A set of strings is undecidable if there is no Turing machine that decides membership of the set.